# javascript fusion charts not appearing in the new window

Tags: fusioncharts

I have a web page where fusion chart is rendered, my requirement is to bring this chart to a new window and send it for print.

function that I am using for bring the new window is

```
 function printBtn(){
    var prtContent1 = document.getElementById("chartdiv");      
    var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');

    WinPrint.document.write(prtContent1.innerHTML);    

    WinPrint.document.close();
    WinPrint.focus();
    WinPrint.print();
    WinPrint.close();
    }
```

I picked one html file from the FusionChart XT folder and put a 'print' btn.
In the local m/c its works as expected. But when I put the same code and set of js/swf files in the server, the chart in the new page looks like this..
[image: server_img]

As you can see..only the labels appear and the chart is not seen.
What could I be missing here. Our application is hosted on IBM Websphere App Server. Am bringing javascript charts using FusionChart XT.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using to replicate the chart is not a standard method to copy `SVG` or `VML`. A number of things will not be copied to the `WinPrint` window by using `innerHTML` method. Instead try this:

1. Load `fusioncharts.js` in the new window
2. Then recreate the chart on that window by cloning it from source.